# Updating a column with Numbers

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, I am new in this field trying to understand how to achieve updating a column from table with Numbering of each row from that table. (from 1 to ~).
Table name PRODUCTS.
Column name NUMBER.
I want to mention from that the start that Field Number is totally different from the ID. Products are inserting and deleting and ID is autoincrementing. But Field Number is UPDATING with the number of rows.
So I want to achieve to have a button while submiting to update the field Number with corespondent number of rows.

Please suggest some PHP/MySql script which could help me to update the Field NUMBER with numbers. I would much appreciate any of your suggestion. Thank you in advance!

My script is wrong:

```
$rank="0";
$q = mysql_query("SELECT NUMBER FROM PRODUCTS");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($q); 
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = @mysql_fetch_row($q)){ 
mysql_query("update PRODUCTS set NUMBER=$rank++ where ID IS NOT NULL");
}
```

edited:
Database now:

```
ID  NAME   NUMBER
________________
201  Apple  3
203  Orange 5
204  Grape 17
```

should be after updating:

```
ID  NAME   NUMBER
________________
201  Apple  1
203  Orange 2
204  Grape  3
```

Comment: can you give some sample data here to make it more clear like how is ur table and how you want it?

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place?

Comment: in the first place I would like to UPDATE the entire Column NUMBER starting with number 1 and next numbers 2,3,4... and so on

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @rank:=0;
update tablename
set NUMBER=@rank:=@rank+1
```

Comment: Nice I thing this should be the way, but How to use it in PHP?

Comment: use the whole query and execute in php

Comment: add at the end `ORDER BY ID ASC` so it update values by correct order

Comment: I do something wrong, please write me an example how to apply this in PHP

Comment: may be you can try this link for more details on php - http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-execute.php

Comment: thank`s, all exemples is how to update a Row, but I need an entire Column